# How to OAuth 2.0 login using Chrome custom tabs (Fitbit API)

Tags: android, oauth-2.0, fitbit, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

Fitbit API doesn't support webview anymore.

So, I studied chrome custom tabs and applied in my app.

But after login, when I pressed this pink button(allow button), nothing happened.(Image below)

[image: Fitbit API Login Image]

How can I receive access token and store it in app?

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

When authorizing agains the Fitbit API, you need to provide a `redirect_uri`, which is where the user will be taken after logging in. You need to provide a uri that will take the user back to your application.

To achieve that, create an [intent filter](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/intent-filter-element.html) and add a [data](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element.html) tag with a custom scheme, such as `myapplication://logincallback` to the Activity you want to handle the login.

The intent filter will look something like this:

```
<intent-filter . . . >
    <data android:scheme="myapplication" android:host="logincallback" />
    . . .
</intent-filter>
```

Now, set the `redirect_uri` as `mypplication://logincallback` to the authorization step of the flow, and when the user clicks the pink button, it should open the Activity you added the intent filter.

You will be able to retrieve the parameters inside your activity by calling [getData](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#getData()) on the Intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot!!
I'll try this solution tomorrow.
Have a nice day!

Comment: seems like a workaround, I need to create an extra activity just to get the code. Is there any good solution same like webviews for chrome tabs ?

Comment: This is not working. I have a url just for call back so a page opens with not found error and only after a reload the activity gets triggered :(

Comment: @Cloud I'm having the same issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: @C2H6O did either of you ever figure this out? Running into this issue myself.

Comment: @russjr08 No, I'm not sure if it is possible. I ended up using the standard approach of implicit Intents which worked well for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="logincallback"
                android:pathPattern=".*"
                android:scheme="myapp" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Suppose you have redirect_uri `myapp://logincallback`, then add above code in your activity in Manifest xml file and it will work.