# Auto Close Chrome Custom Tabs

Tags: google-chrome, chrome-custom-tabs

We are using Chrome Custom Tabs for payment re-directions and we have found that there is no such methods for auto close when payment gateway re-directs us to the app. Please suggest what need to do, I am totally stuck at the end of payment re-direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you control the redirection URL, you can do the same approach used for OAuth login, which is to redirect the user to a custom URL scheme that is handled by your application.

Check the answer for the question below. It is an OAuth question, but the implementation on the Custom Tabs side should be the same:
[How to OAuth 2.0 login using Chrome custom tabs (Fitbit API)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33772515/how-to-oauth-2-0-login-using-chrome-custom-tabs-fitbit-api)